# SharePoint 2010 send email

Tags: email, timer-jobs

I have a timer job that will get ListItem based on some criteria.
After I gathered all the items, I will send an email based on the Modified column and cc that email based on the Created By column.
Currently, when I run my timer job, I will get 38658 items.
My question is will it cause any issue when sending out email 38658 times one by one using the SPUtility.SendEmail method.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Better, You can use SharePoint Designer Workflow Actions of:

1) Pause until Date Action

2) Pause for Duration Action

and finally you can also send email by using a workflow action called

3) Send Email

Using the Send Email action, you can able to configure the To Address, Subject, CC, Body of the Email.

Comment: The bonus of using workflow is that SharePoint handles the potential performance issue by running the workflows in batches.